# Hibernate composed key issue

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key

I have two tables  as below.

```
create table A(id int, type char(1), desc varchar(32))

create table B(id int, 
               aId1 int not null, 
               aId2 int null,
               mapDefName varchar(11))
```

In table B, records needs to referenced to two Ids from table A which aId1 is not null and aId2 column can be null during insert. **But these aId1 and aId2 columns can not be PK.**

The records from TableA which's type column value is "x" needs to be mapped to TableB:aId1 column.

The records from TableA which's type column value is "y" needs to be mapped to TableB:aId2 column.

For example;

```
Table A;

id       type      desc
----     ----      -----
12         x       something...
13         y       something...
14         x       something...
15         y       something...
16         x       something...
17         y       something...
```

---

```
Table B;

id       aId1    aId2        mapDefName
----     ----    -----       ----------
1         12       13         sth...
2         12       13         sth...
3         12                  sth...       
4         14                  sth...       
5         14                  sth...       
6         14       15         sth...      
7         16       17         sth...
8         16       17         sth...
```

How can I code this mapping with annotations in hibernate?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate annotations - Filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters)

and [examples](https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example)

In your case, you should define TableA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TableA")
@FilterDef(name="studentFilter", parameters={
        @ParamDef(name="type", type="string" )
})
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="idFilter", condition="type = :type")
} )
public class TableA{
...    
}
```

Then use session enableFilter()

```
Filter filter = session.enableFilter("studentFilter");
filter.setParameter("type", "x"); 

session.disableFilter("studentFilter");
```

I didn't use this feature before, just some guide. Hope it helps.